# Text Block Text Animation Like Live Tile Text

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

Hi every One See the Below  Image
[image]

in this Screen that 3 Blocks are images  and i am trying to Bind some text to that Text Block and display with some time intervals with Live tile Look and feels. Can any One Sugest How can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mimic Live Tiles, I suggest that you take a look at [The Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/). It contains the `HubTile` control which is *live* and is probably the thing you are looking for.

If not, you have the source code and you can check how they did it. This way you can replicate the behavior and then customize it.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Toni Petrina But How can i Bind All my data to Single Hub tile and display with some time gap

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. You use binding the same way as you would use with other controls. As for the time gap, not sure about that.